# Show that all the n-dimentional vectors that add up to one is convex and compact set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to prove that
$ A = \{x=(x_1,.....,x_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m : x_i \geq 0 , \quad \forall i = 1,2,....,m $|$\sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i = 1 \}$
is convex  and compact set

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know the definitions of convex and of compact? Are you getting stuck in applying those definitions? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: For compacteness , my i thought that for every cover of A there exist the finite cover $\cup {x_i} , therefore is compact .

Comment: for convexity i tried for every two points in A , to show that the line connecting them is in A, but i could't

Comment: $A$ is a set of $n$-tuples, $x_i$ is a single number, so it doesn't make sense to say the union of the $x_i$ covers $A$. You need a union of subsets of $A$ to cover $A$, and $x_i$ isn't a subset of $A$. It may be easier to use the closed-and-bounded characterization of compact sets. For convexity, can you work out what the points on the line connecting two points of $A$ look like? A formula for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the convexity:
If $x,y \in A$ you have to prove that for every $t \in [0,1]$ the point $z=tx+(1-t)y$ is still in $A$. Now
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 z = tx + \left( {1 - t} \right)y = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {tx_i  + \left( {1 - t} \right)y_i }  =  \\ 
  = t\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {x_i  + \left( {1 - t} \right)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {y_i } }  = t + \left( {1 - t} \right) = 1 \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
Hence $z \in A$.

For the compacteness:you have that $A$ is bounded because $A \subseteq [0,1]^m= [0,1]\times...[0,1]$ and it is closed since it contains  its boundary. Therefore $A$ is compact.

Comment: thank you, but i don't see why A contains its boundary?

Comment: Since, as subset of $\mathbb R^m$ every point is a boundary point. I suggest, just to have a better understanding, to draw a pic for $n=2$ and $n=3$. You will see that in the former case $A$ is a segment in $\mathbb R^2$ while, in the latter, in a triangle in $\mathbb R^3$.